# Is it possible to configure webpack so the evaluation of a bundle will terminate early if a certain condition is met?

Tags: webpack

I am wondering if it's possible to configure Webpack in such a way that it adds some kind of initial validation code to a bundle that prevents the rest of the bundle from executing if a condition fails.

An example of that code would be quitting early if the browser's user agent does not agree with our support list.

I also don't want to post-process the bundle wrapping it in a function as that will break source maps.

Answer (score 0):

You can define webpack's entry point into an array which the first file will contain an [IIFE](http://IIFE%20(Immediately%20Invoked%20Function%20Expression)) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) that checks what ever you need.

If the condition is not met, throw an exception.

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: [ 
    './src/condition-checker.js',
    './src/your-app-origianl-entry.js'
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

For more info check [webpack's docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/)